# Тags for different types of user interfaces

Tags: discussion, tags

There're a lot of different types of user interfaces:

- A **natural user interface** (NUI) is the common parlance used by designers and developers of human-machine interfaces to refer to a user interface that is (1) effectively invisible, or becomes invisible with successive learned interactions, to its users, and (2) is based on nature or natural elements. **Example**: [Relationship between anthropomorphism and NUI?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16683/relationship-between-anthropomorphism-and-nui)
- A **kinetic user interface** (KUI) is an emerging type of user interfaces that allow users to interact with computing devices through the motion of objects and bodies. **Example**: [UI gestures for Kinect, Kinect-type devices](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3844/ui-gestures-for-kinect-kinect-type-devices), [What UI designs are a good fit for the Kinect / PrimeSense DevKit?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2884/what-ui-designs-are-a-good-fit-for-the-kinect-primesense-devkit)

  <strike>-  A **organic user interface** (OUI) is a user interface with interaction techniques that use the physical shape and position of a device to control it.</strike>
- A **tangible user interface** (TUI) is a user interface in which a person interacts with digital information through the physical environment.

Would be these tags useful?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're coming at this from the wrong direction really. We don't arbitrarily create tags for people to use, tags are only created when a question is asked that would fit a particular tag that hasn't already been created.

So, if and when a question is asked that fits any of these tags then we can create them, but it isn't possible to create a tag without a question for it - and even if you could tags that have no associated questions just get automatically deleted in the general site clearup that happens overnight.

If you have some questions about any of these interfaces then go ahead and ask those and tag them with the appropriate term, or if there are existing questions on the site that you think would benefit from these tags then feel free to add the tag to them, but we need questions about the topics first before tags can be created.

Comment: I see, I've added some examples for two of them.

Comment: @IgorGubaidulin: You can suggest an edit to any of those questions, and add the tag(s) as part of that edit. If approved they will be created and the tags will be available for use for other questions.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly I just came to meta to post a question about these very tags.

I have no problem with the concept of granular interface tags, my issue is using the acronym.

A tag of `KUI` is not useful to those who are not already familiar with the acronym.

Should the tag not be `kinetic-user-interface` or `natural-user-interface` with a descriptive tag wiki?

Comment: Maybe with tag aliases `kinetic-UI` and `natural-UI`?

Comment: That sounds good to me!